# Why do I get three user outputs instead of 2

Tags: perl

I am having a problem with the output of this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

# Opening the file timelog.txt, the "<" indicates that the file is being opened in read mode
open(DATA, "<timelog.txt") or die "Couldn't open file timelog.txt, $!";
# Looping through each line in this file, this each line can be accesed with $_
while(<DATA>) {
    # In the line ($_), we search for patters
    # We first search the pattern " pts/"
    $_ =~ m/ pts\//;
    # We store the text before this pattern in the variable userId
    $userId = "$`";
    # We now search for the patter "Word Number Number:Number - Number:Number"
    # This pattern is found at the end of each string
    $_ =~ m/(\w+) (\d+) (\d+):(\d+) - (\d+):(\d+)/;
    # The required variables, i.e. the month start hour, start minutes, end hour and end minutes are extracted
    ($month, $hours1, $minutes1, $hours2, $minutes2) = ($1, $3, $4, $5, $6);
    # $userId." ".$month is used to concatenate the userId along with month with a space between them
    # the . is used to concatenate
    # If the key already exists, we increase the value of time
    if(exists($store{$userId." ".$month})){
        $store{$userId." ".$month} += (($hours2 - $hours1)*60) + $minutes2 - $minutes1;
    } else {
        # If the key does not exist we create a new key value pair
        $store{$userId." ".$month} = (($hours2 - $hours1)*60) + $minutes2 - $minutes1;
    }
    # Note that the key is concatenation of userId and the month
}
# We now loop through the elements and print them
foreach $key (keys %store){
    print "$key $store{$key} minutes\n";
}
```

`timelog.txt`:

```
maclawty796          pts/1        10.1.28.122      Mon Oct 24 09:18 - 09:20  
maclawty796          pts/1        ip-64-134-238-2.      Fri Oct 21 14:23 - 14:25  
maclawty796          pts/2        10.1.28.122           Fri Oct 21 09:42 - 09:55  
ehowe                   pts/3        10.1.28.204           Fri Oct 21 09:28 - 09:29  
kho398     pts/2        10.1.28.233           Fri Oct 21 09:22 - 09:34  
maclawty796          pts/1        10.1.28.122           Fri Oct 21 09:20 - 09:55  
maclawty796          pts/1        75.27.188.106    Thu Oct 20 21:09 - 21:23  
maclawty796          pts/1        10.1.28.120           Fri Oct 14 09:46 - 09:52  
kho398     pts/2        10.1.28.124      Thu Oct 13 09:29 - 09:30  
maclawty796          pts/1        10.1.28.128      Thu Oct 13 09:28 - 09:51  
maclawty796          pts/2        adsl-75-30-120-1 Wed Oct 12 20:35 - 20:35  
maclawty796          pts/1        75-30-120-13.lig Wed Oct 12 19:27 - 19:33  
hturner      pts/1        tom-nilsons-macb Wed Oct 12 13:30 - 13:32  
nnt        pts/2        99-59-5-115.ligh Tue Oct 11 15:51 - 15:54  
nnt        pts/1        hitami  yamas Tue Oct 11 15:31 - 17:42  
maclawty796          pts/1        leda.local       Tue Oct 11 14:10 - 14:11  
ehowe                   pts/2        10.1.28.126      Tue Oct 11 09:21 - 09:24  
maclawty796          pts/2        10.1.28.123      Tue Oct 11 09:01 - 09:08  
nnt        pts/1        10.1.28.210      Tue Oct 11 08:53 - 12:02  
nnt        pts/1        hitami  yamas Tue Oct 11 07:53 - 07:54  
nnt        pts/1        hitami  yamas Tue Oct 11 07:48 - 07:52  
maclawty796          pts/1        adsl-75-16-61-10 Mon Oct 10 23:18 - 23:20  
nnt        pts/1        99-59-5-115.ligh Mon Oct 10 22:16 - 23:11  
nnt        pts/1        99-59-5-115.ligh Mon Oct 10 22:09 - 22:14  
nnt        pts/1        99-59-5-115.ligh Mon Oct 10 21:27 - 21:31  
maclawty796          pts/2        adsl-75-16-61-10 Mon Oct 10 20:46 - 20:47  
nnt        pts/1        99-59-5-115.ligh Mon Oct 10 20:19 - 21:22  
kho398     pts/2        108-93-76-161.li Mon Oct 10 19:15 - 19:19  
kho398     pts/2        108-93-76-161.li Mon Oct 10 19:09 - 19:12  
jimquinn409           pts/2        10.1.8.148       Mon Oct 10 17:40 - 17:46  
jimquinn409           pts/2        10.1.8.148       Mon Oct 10 17:38 - 17:39  
nnt        pts/1        99-59-5-115.ligh Mon Oct 10 17:19 - 20:01  
jimquinn409           pts/2        10.1.8.148       Mon Oct 10 16:29 - 16:33  
jimquinn409           pts/2        10.1.8.148       Mon Oct 10 16:27 - 16:28  
nnt        pts/1        99-59-5-115.ligh Mon Oct 10 16:01 - 17:18  
nnt        pts/1        99-59-5-115.ligh Mon Oct 10 15:11 - 15:59  
maclawty796          pts/1        10.1.31.27       Mon Oct 10 14:16 - 14:21  
johnhouston       pts/2        10.1.31.220      Mon Oct 10 12:01 - 12:17  
jimquinn409           pts/1        ubuntu.local     Mon Oct 10 11:58 - 12:04  
kho398     pts/1        10.1.28.244      Mon Oct 10 09:07 - 09:17  
maclawty796          pts/1        10.1.31.27       Mon Oct 10 08:45 - 08:49  
honeill      pts/1        99-59-7-95.light Mon Oct 10 05:42 - 07:14  
honeill      pts/1        99-59-7-95.light Mon Oct 10 04:26 - 05:26  
kho398     pts/1        108-93-76-161.li Sun Oct  9 23:12 - 23:13  
kho398     pts/1        108-93-76-161.li Sun Oct  9 20:56 - 21:15  
kho398     pts/1        108-93-76-161.li Sun Oct  9 20:54 - 20:56  
kho398     pts/1        108-93-76-161.li Sun Oct  9 20:51 - 20:52  
kho398     pts/2        108-93-76-161.li Sun Oct  9 20:40 - 20:48  
maclawty796          pts/1        adsl-75-27-233-7 Sun Oct  9 20:30 - 20:42  
kho398     pts/1        108-93-76-161.li Sun Oct  9 20:15 - 20:19  
johnhouston       pts/2        99-176-56-113.li Sun Oct  9 19:58 - 20:04  
kho398     pts/1        108-93-76-161.li Sun Oct  9 19:48 - 20:00  
kho398     pts/3        108-93-76-161.li Sun Oct  9 19:36 - 19:48  
kho398     pts/3        108-93-76-161.li Sun Oct  9 19:35 - 19:36  
kho398     pts/3        108-93-76-161.li Sun Oct  9 19:32 - 19:34  
johnhouston       pts/2        99-176-56-113.li Sun Oct  9 19:29 - 19:55  
nnt        pts/1        99-59-5-115.ligh Sun Oct  9 18:29 - 19:45  
kho398     pts/4        108-93-76-161.li Sun Oct  9 18:27 - 19:32  
johnhouston       pts/3        99-176-56-113.li Sun Oct  9 17:12 - 19:28  
nnt        pts/2        99-59-5-115.ligh Sun Oct  9 15:38 - 18:31  
nnt        pts/1        99-59-5-115.ligh Sun Oct  9 15:36 - 18:29  
maclawty796          pts/1        10.1.31.27            Fri Oct  7 13:55 - 14:09  
maclawty796          pts/1        10.1.31.27            Fri Oct  7 13:39 - 13:41  
johnhouston       pts/1        99-176-56-113.li      Fri Oct  7 12:07 - 13:29  
edrodri5722     pts/1        10.1.28.171           Fri Oct  7 09:49 - 09:52  
kho398     pts/1        10.1.28.116           Fri Oct  7 09:46 - 09:48  
jimquinn409           pts/1        10.1.28.200           Fri Oct  7 09:39 - 09:40  
jimquinn409           pts/3        10.1.28.200           Fri Oct  7 08:56 - 09:42  
nnt        pts/3        hitami  yamas      Fri Oct  7 07:52 - 07:59  
nnt        pts/2        99-59-5-115.ligh      Fri Oct  7 07:15 - 09:18  
nnt        pts/1        99-59-5-115.ligh      Fri Oct  7 07:13 - 09:30  
kho398     pts/1        108-93-76-161.li      Fri Oct  7 01:15 - 01:17  
kho398     pts/1        108-93-76-161.li      Fri Oct  7 01:14 - 01:15  
kho398     pts/1        108-93-76-161.li      Fri Oct  7 01:12 - 01:13  
kho398     pts/2        108-93-76-161.li      Fri Oct  7 01:06 - 01:12  
kho398     pts/2        108-93-76-161.li      Fri Oct  7 01:04 - 01:05  
kho398     pts/2        108-93-76-161.li      Fri Oct  7 00:53 - 01:04  
johnhouston       pts/1        99-176-56-113.li      Fri Oct  7 00:25 - 01:08  
edrodri5722     pts/2        10.1.31.151      Thu Oct  6 22:27 - 22:48  
honeill      pts/1        jst-pc.local     Thu Oct  6 22:19 - 22:53  
nnt        pts/1        99-59-5-115.ligh Thu Oct  6 19:44 - 19:54  
honeill      pts/6        jst-pc.local     Thu Oct  6 19:43 - 22:19  
edrodri5722     pts/5        10.1.31.151      Thu Oct  6 19:40 - 22:40  
ehowe                   pts/2        ubuntu.local     Thu Oct  6 19:40 - 20:36  
hturner      pts/2        97-90-193-108.dh Thu Oct  6 19:12 - 19:22  
jimquinn409           pts/3        10.1.8.129       Thu Oct  6 18:21 - 22:54  
jimquinn409           pts/5        10.1.8.129       Thu Oct  6 17:59 - 18:08  
jimquinn409           pts/5        10.1.8.129       Thu Oct  6 17:55 - 17:58  
johnhouston       pts/4        99-176-56-113.li Thu Oct  6 17:13 - 22:15  
johnhouston       pts/4        99-176-56-113.li Thu Oct  6 17:09 - 17:12  
johnhouston       pts/4        99-176-56-113.li Thu Oct  6 17:07 - 17:08  
jimquinn409           pts/3        ubuntu.local     Thu Oct  6 16:56 - 18:14  
hturner      pts/2        97-90-193-108.dh Thu Oct  6 16:43 - 18:43  
nnt        pts/1        99-59-5-115.ligh Thu Oct  6 16:42 - 19:43  
jimquinn409           pts/1        ubuntu.local     Thu Oct  6 16:16 - 16:25  
hturner      pts/4        108-67-52-153.li Thu Oct  6 15:18 - 16:10  
hturner      pts/3        108-67-52-153.li Thu Oct  6 15:17 - 16:10  
honeill      pts/3        10.0.18.162      Thu Oct  6 14:00 - 14:15  
hturner      pts/2        10.1.13.227      Thu Oct  6 13:01 - 15:42  
hturner      pts/1        10.1.13.227      Thu Oct  6 13:01 - 15:41  
maclawty796          pts/6        10.1.31.27       Thu Oct  6 10:02 - 10:11  
hturner      pts/5        tom-nilsons-macb Thu Oct  6 10:00 - 12:17  
hturner      pts/4        tom-nilsons-macb Thu Oct  6 09:58 - 12:17  
edrodri5722     pts/4        10.1.28.135      Thu Oct  6 09:51 - 09:52  
jimquinn409           pts/1        10.1.28.126      Thu Oct  6 09:49 - 12:06  
jimquinn409           pts/4        10.1.28.126      Thu Oct  6 09:41 - 09:41  
jimquinn409           pts/4        10.1.28.126      Thu Oct  6 09:29 - 09:35  
hturner      pts/2        10.1.28.167      Thu Oct  6 09:28 - 12:05  
mvan682        pts/8        10.1.28.119      Thu Oct  6 09:17 - 09:18  
honeill      pts/7        10.1.28.163      Thu Oct  6 09:15 - 09:57  
jimquinn409           pts/2        10.1.28.126      Thu Oct  6 09:15 - 09:21  
jimquinn409           pts/7        10.1.28.126      Thu Oct  6 09:13 - 09:14  
jimquinn409           pts/7        10.1.28.126      Thu Oct  6 09:08 - 09:11  
ehowe                   pts/6        10.1.28.155      Thu Oct  6 09:07 - 09:28  
maclawty796          pts/5        10.1.28.123      Thu Oct  6 09:05 - 09:28  
maclawty796          pts/4        10.1.28.123      Thu Oct  6 09:04 - 09:28  
hturner      pts/3        10.1.28.167      Thu Oct  6 09:01 - 12:06  
honeill      pts/2        10.1.28.163      Thu Oct  6 08:59 - 09:14  
edrodri5722     pts/1        10.1.28.135      Thu Oct  6 08:56 - 09:47  
ehowe                   pts/2        10.1.28.155      Thu Oct  6 08:49 - 08:54  
maclawty796          pts/1        10.1.31.27       Thu Oct  6 08:24 - 08:53  
edrodri5722     pts/1        76-202-53-118.li Thu Oct  6 05:11 - 05:23  
kho398     pts/1        108-93-76-161.li Thu Oct  6 02:18 - 02:23  
kho398     pts/2        108-93-76-161.li Thu Oct  6 00:36 - 02:04  
ehowe                   pts/1        10.0.17.151      Thu Oct  6 00:29 - 00:41  
jimquinn409           pts/3        76-202-52-236.li Thu Oct  6 00:21 - 02:28  
ehowe                   pts/1        10.0.17.151      Thu Oct  6 00:11 - 00:22  
ehowe                   pts/1        10.0.17.180      Thu Oct  6 00:05 - 00:11  
ehowe                   pts/1        10.0.17.151      Wed Oct  5 23:17 - 23:26  
ehowe                   pts/1        10.1.6.218       Wed Oct  5 22:06 - 22:20  
ehowe                   pts/1        10.1.6.218       Wed Oct  5 21:38 - 21:48  
maclawty796          pts/2        adsl-75-16-59-16 Wed Oct  5 21:04 - 21:07  
ehowe                   pts/3        10.1.6.218       Wed Oct  5 20:53 - 21:28  
ehowe                   pts/2        10.1.6.218       Wed Oct  5 20:46 - 21:02  
maclawty796          pts/3        adsl-75-16-59-16 Wed Oct  5 19:20 - 20:04  
nnt        pts/2        99-59-5-115.ligh Wed Oct  5 19:09 - 20:22  
kho398     pts/1        108-93-76-161.li Wed Oct  5 19:00 - 21:31  
maclawty796          pts/1        10.1.31.27       Wed Oct  5 15:27 - 16:28  
maclawty796          pts/1        :0.0             Wed Oct  5 15:10 - 15:25  
maclawty796          pts/1        10.1.31.27       Wed Oct  5 13:34 - 13:42  
maclawty796          pts/1        10.1.31.27       Wed Oct  5 13:29 - 13:30  
nnt        pts/2        99-59-5-115.ligh Wed Oct  5 10:51 - 13:15  
nnt        pts/1        166.205.141.16   Wed Oct  5 09:28 - 12:07  
honeill      pts/4        76-202-53-118.li Tue Oct  4 21:12 - 22:47  
honeill      pts/4        76-202-53-118.li Tue Oct  4 21:02 - 21:11  
edrodri5722     pts/1        76-202-53-118.li Tue Oct  4 20:46 - 22:48  
jimquinn409           pts/1        10.1.8.233       Tue Oct  4 20:37 - 20:43  
edrodri5722     pts/4        76-202-53-118.li Tue Oct  4 20:29 - 20:32  
edrodri5722     pts/4        76-202-53-118.li Tue Oct  4 20:02 - 20:09  
edrodri5722     pts/3        76-202-53-118.li Tue Oct  4 19:43 - 21:51  
nnt        pts/2        166.205.141.16   Tue Oct  4 19:19 - 21:54  
nnt        pts/1        166.205.141.16   Tue Oct  4 18:29 - 20:33  
nnt        pts/3        108-195-113-206. Tue Oct  4 16:47 - 17:18  
maclawty796          pts/2        10.1.31.27       Tue Oct  4 16:43 - 16:59  
maclawty796          pts/2        10.1.31.27       Tue Oct  4 16:27 - 16:32  
maclawty796          pts/3        10.1.31.27       Tue Oct  4 16:26 - 16:26  
maclawty796          pts/2        10.1.31.27       Tue Oct  4 15:05 - 16:26  
nnt        pts/1        108-195-113-206. Tue Oct  4 14:40 - 17:32  
kho398     pts/1        108-93-76-161.li Tue Oct  4 02:22 - 03:08  
edrodri5722     pts/1        76-202-53-118.li Mon Oct  3 22:32 - 22:36  
edrodri5722     pts/1        76-202-53-118.li Mon Oct  3 20:45 - 22:31  
edrodri5722     pts/1        76-202-53-118.li Mon Oct  3 20:44 - 20:44  
nnt        pts/1        108-195-113-206. Mon Oct  3 16:07 - 19:54  
jimquinn409           pts/1        10.1.28.142      Mon Oct  3 09:04 - 09:47  
kho398     pts/1        10.1.28.199      Mon Oct  3 09:01 - 09:02  
kho398     pts/1        108-93-76-161.li Sun Oct  2 22:27 - 22:29  
kho398     pts/1        108-93-76-161.li Sun Oct  2 19:18 - 19:23  
kho398     pts/1        108-93-76-161.li Sun Oct  2 18:51 - 19:17  
edrodri5722     pts/1        76-202-53-118.li Sun Oct  2 18:28 - 18:47  
kho398     pts/1        108-93-76-161.li Sun Oct  2 17:04 - 18:16  
maclawty796          pts/1        adsl-75-28-65-14 Sat Oct  1 21:15 - 21:32  
maclawty796          pts/1        10.1.31.27            Fri Sep 30 15:19 - 15:20  
hturner      pts/1        108-67-52-153.li      Fri Sep 30 11:06 - 11:13  
mvan682        pts/4        10.1.28.119           Fri Sep 30 09:50 - 09:50  
kho398     pts/3        10.1.28.199           Fri Sep 30 09:49 - 09:50  
kho398     pts/3        10.1.28.199           Fri Sep 30 09:29 - 09:46  
mvan682        pts/4        10.1.28.121           Fri Sep 30 09:04 - 09:12  
kho398     pts/3        10.1.28.199           Fri Sep 30 09:02 - 09:21  
jimquinn409           pts/2        10.1.28.142           Fri Sep 30 09:02 - 11:27  
mvan682        pts/2        10.1.28.121           Fri Sep 30 09:02 - 09:02  
kho398     pts/2        10.1.28.199           Fri Sep 30 09:00 - 09:01  
maclawty796          pts/1        10.1.28.212           Fri Sep 30 08:57 - 09:51  
maclawty796          pts/1        adsl-75-28-22-24 Thu Sep 29 20:16 - 20:35  
nnt        pts/1        108-195-113-206. Thu Sep 29 16:24 - 17:14  
jimquinn409           pts/2        ubuntu.local     Thu Sep 29 15:24 - 17:40  
maclawty796          pts/2        enoch-tang-ima Thu Sep 29 14:21 - 14:22  
maclawty796          pts/2        10.1.31.27       Thu Sep 29 14:08 - 14:09  
johnhouston       pts/2        187.34   -32-94.dhcp Thu Sep 29 13:25 - 13:40  
johnhouston       pts/1        187.34   -32-94.dhcp Thu Sep 29 13:10 - 15:25  
mvan682        pts/3        10.1.28.119      Thu Sep 29 09:47 - 09:48  
kho398     pts/2        10.1.28.103      Thu Sep 29 09:47 - 09:51  
kho398     pts/2        10.1.28.103      Thu Sep 29 09:44 - 09:46  
maclawty796          pts/1        10.1.28.105      Thu Sep 29 09:43 - 09:54  
mvan682        pts/3        10.1.28.119      Thu Sep 29 09:23 - 09:24  
edrodri5722     pts/2        10.1.28.199      Thu Sep 29 09:20 - 09:23  
jimquinn409           pts/1        10.1.28.142      Thu Sep 29 09:20 - 09:28  
kho398     pts/3        10.1.28.103      Thu Sep 29 09:08 - 09:15  
ehowe                   pts/2        10.1.28.106      Thu Sep 29 09:07 - 09:10  
maclawty796          pts/1        10.1.28.105      Thu Sep 29 09:05 - 09:15  
ehowe                   pts/1        10.1.28.106      Thu Sep 29 08:51 - 08:52  
ehowe                   pts/1        10.1.28.225      Thu Sep 29 08:47 - 08:48  
maclawty796          pts/2        10.1.31.27       Thu Sep 29 08:41 - 08:56  
ehowe                   pts/1        10.1.28.225      Thu Sep 29 08:40 - 08:46  
honeill      pts/1        99-59-7-95.light Thu Sep 29 03:50 - 03:56  
edrodri5722     pts/1        76-202-53-118.li Thu Sep 29 01:03 - 01:04  
edrodri5722     pts/1        76-202-53-118.li Thu Sep 29 00:59 - 01:03  
johnhouston       pts/1        187.34   -32-94.dhcp Thu Sep 29 00:49 - 00:55  
johnhouston       pts/1        187.34   -32-94.dhcp Wed Sep 28 23:40 - 23:43  
ehowe                   pts/1        10.0.17.91       Wed Sep 28 21:57 - 22:12  
ehowe                   pts/1        10.0.17.91       Wed Sep 28 21:23 - 21:53  
kho398     pts/2        10.1.8.83        Wed Sep 28 20:16 - 20:18  
kho398     pts/2        10.1.8.83        Wed Sep 28 20:13 - 20:13  
kho398     pts/2        10.1.8.83        Wed Sep 28 20:10 - 20:11  
kho398     pts/2        10.1.8.83        Wed Sep 28 20:06 - 20:07  
kho398     pts/2        10.1.8.83        Wed Sep 28 19:53 - 20:00  
ehowe                   pts/1        10.0.17.91       Wed Sep 28 19:17 - 21:11  
jimquinn409           pts/1        10.1.8.85        Wed Sep 28 15:25 - 16:22  
maclawty796          pts/1        10.1.31.27       Wed Sep 28 14:32 - 14:37  
kho398     pts/1        108-93-76-161.li Wed Sep 28 00:28 - 01:05  
kho398     pts/1        108-93-76-161.li Wed Sep 28 00:25 - 00:28  
maclawty796          pts/1        75.16.62.214     Tue Sep 27 22:32 - 22:44  
nnt        pts/1        enoch-tang-ima Tue Sep 27 16:26 - 16:26  
nnt        pts/2        psc147-04-4.loca Tue Sep 27 15:42 - 16:22  
johnhouston       pts/1        psc147-04-3.loca Tue Sep 27 15:40 - 16:22  
maclawty796          pts/1        psc147-04-3.loca Tue Sep 27 15:37 - 15:37  
maclawty796          pts/1        psc147-04.local  Tue Sep 27 15:26 - 15:26  
hturner      pts/1        10.1.13.49       Tue Sep 27 12:52 - 12:58  
hturner      pts/1        10.1.13.49       Tue Sep 27 12:50 - 12:51  
jimquinn409           pts/2        10.1.31.27       Tue Sep 27 10:06 - 10:06  
honeill      pts/2        10.1.31.27       Tue Sep 27 10:05 - 10:06  
maclawty796          pts/1        10.1.31.27       Tue Sep 27 10:04 - 10:07  
maclawty796          pts/2        10.1.28.120      Tue Sep 27 09:42 - 09:52  
edrodri5722     pts/1        10.1.28.207      Tue Sep 27 09:41 - 09:46  
mvan682        pts/1        10.1.28.157      Tue Sep 27 09:39 - 09:39  
mvan682        pts/1        10.1.28.157      Tue Sep 27 09:33 - 09:37  
maclawty796          pts/1        10.1.31.27       Tue Sep 27 08:37 - 08:54  
maclawty796          pts/1        adsl-75-30-121-1 Mon Sep 26 22:51 - 23:06  
maclawty796          pts/1        75-30-121-143.li Mon Sep 26 22:44 - 22:49  
edrodri5722     pts/2        10.1.31.27       Mon Sep 26 12:14 - 12:14  
edrodri5722     pts/2        10.1.31.27       Mon Sep 26 12:13 - 12:13  
maclawty796          pts/1        10.1.31.27       Mon Sep 26 12:11 - 12:14  
maclawty796          pts/1        10.1.28.154      Mon Sep 26 09:55 - 09:55
```

I do not know why I am getting 3 outputs for each user (each should be just 2) being the third one an empty one.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.  Thank you for providing sample input.  However, please trim it down to the minimum required to demonstrate the problem.  Then please also show us the exact output you get when you run your script, and what output you would have expected.  (Several people here may insist, rightly and with good intent, that you should also `use strict` and `use warnings`.)

Comment: The output you show here doesn't have three (3) lines for every user...?  It's either 1 line, or 2 lines, or 3 or 4 or 5 ... so what do you mean by "_3 outputs for each user_"?

Comment: Please clarify: Cut down the size of the data to what's necessary to reproduce your problem, provide what output you are getting for this new input, and provide what output you are expecting for this input.

Answer (score 1):

Please make a small change to your code for debug purpose:

at very begin add

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

and output your captured data

```
    # The required variables, i.e. the month start hour, start minutes, end hour and end minutes are extracted
    my ($month, $hours1, $minutes1, $hours2, $minutes2) = ($1, $3, $4, $5, $6);
    my $format = "DEBUG: %-25s %3s %02d:%02d %02d:%02d\n";
    printf $format,$userId, $month, $hours1, $minutes1, $hours2, $minutes2;
    # $userId." ".$month is used to concatenate the userId along with month with a space between them
```

Debug information gives you a clue where the problem is originated from and you will figure out the direction how to correct it.

**NOTE:** your code is flowed as it does not take into an account when login **crosses** midnight hour -- computation will get negative time

The code after a slight modification could look like following (midnight issue still present)

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $fname = shift || 'timelog.txt';

my %store;
my $re = qr|(\w+)\s+pts/\d\s+(.*?)\s+\w{3} (\w{3}) (\d+) (\d+):(\d+) - (\d+):(\d+)|;

# Opening the file timelog.txt, the "<" indicates that the file is being opened in read mode
open(DATA, '<', $fname)
     or die "Couldn't open file timelog.txt, $!";

while(<DATA>) {
    next unless /$re/;
    my($userId,$host,$month,$hours1,$minutes1,$hours2,$minutes2) = ($1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7);
    # $userId." ".$month is used to concatenate the userId along with month with a space between them
    # the . is used to concatenate
    # If the key already exists, we increase the value of time
    if(exists($store{$userId." ".$month})){
        $store{$userId." ".$month} += (($hours2 - $hours1)*60) + $minutes2 - $minutes1;
    } else {
        # If the key does not exist we create a new key value pair
        $store{$userId." ".$month} = (($hours2 - $hours1)*60) + $minutes2 - $minutes1;
    }
    # Note that the key is concatenation of userId and the month
}
# We now loop through the elements and print them
foreach my $key (sort keys %store){
    printf "%-25s - %6d minutes\n", $key, $store{$key};
}
```

Final output

```
edrodri5722 Sep           -   -959 minutes
ehowe Oct                 -   1020 minutes
ehowe Sep                 -   2523 minutes
honeill Oct               -   2883 minutes
honeill Sep               -    -60 minutes
hturner Oct               -   1080 minutes
hturner Sep               -   1440 minutes
jimquinn409 Oct           -   8521 minutes
jimquinn409 Sep           -  -3955 minutes
johnhouston Oct           -   -540 minutes
johnhouston Sep           -   1323 minutes
kho398 Oct                -   1080 minutes
kho398 Sep                -  -4378 minutes
maclawty796 Oct           -   9840 minutes
maclawty796 Sep           -   3182 minutes
mvan682 Sep               -   -240 minutes
nnt Oct                   -  12792 minutes
nnt Sep                   -    542 minutes
```

Reference:
[open](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open),
[regex](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre),
[Perl regular expression quick start](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick)